# Global const char* declared in .h but defined in one of cpp files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, global-variables

I need to declare a constant shared between multiple files, and define it in one of those files.

I want to be able to do something like that.

```
//myHeader.h
const char* strConstant;
```

```
//myFile.cpp
strConstant = myString.c_str;
```

```
//myFile2.cpp
cout<<strConstant<<endl;
```

How?

I tried used extern but maybe i used it bad, its a large explanation.

Comment: Closed as duplicate. Everything you need to know is answered there.

Comment: Why not just `const inline std::string strConstant = "Foo";` ? Keep it simple.